# Getting a material's asset path to use it later using playerprefs, but code doesn't work

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

In this code I tried to get the asset path for a material (component, not sure if that's important to specify), but when I try to display the output in the debug log it just returns nothing. Also, the playerprefs stuff I set isn't working either, please help. EDIT!!! I found out that when trying targeting a component of a gameobject, the code just targets the object; therefore the code isn't looking for a material asset, it's looking for the object the material is on.

`

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEditor;

public class CustomData : MonoBehaviour
{
    const string MatKey = "material";
    Renderer rend;
    string matpath;

    void Start()
    {
        //Playerprefs
        string material = PlayerPrefs.GetString(MatKey);
        matpath = material;

        //Sets material to desired material
        rend = GetComponent<Renderer>();
        rend.material = (Material)AssetDatabase.LoadAssetAtPath(matpath, typeof(Material));
    }

    void Update()
    {
        //Gets renderer and asset path of material
        rend = GetComponent<Renderer>();
        matpath = AssetDatabase.GetAssetPath(rend.material);
        Debug.Log(matpath);
        PlayerPrefs.SetString(MatKey, matpath);
        PlayerPrefs.Save();
    }
}
```

`

I've tried like a billion documents and stack overflow replies from other people to 0 success.

Comment: Any code contained in the UnityEditor namespace is only usable in the editor.  You should use EditorPrefs for storing the values in editor.

Comment: Can you please elaborate? Sorry, I'm slow.

Comment: AssetDatabase is only usable in the editor.  It will not work during runtime.  If you are wanting to do this in your game, you will have to do things differently.  This doesn't look like editor code, which is why i brought this up.